# PHP 5.5.0 w/ Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 - No sqlsrv_connect()?

Tags: php, windows, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5, sqlsrv

I have the following environment:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

I want to use the new PHP 5.5.0 version, which works just fine per sé, but I can't connect to the MSSQL server due to the lack of current drivers.

For my previous PHP 5.4.15 version, I used the official Microsoft drivers from [>here<](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Is there yet any possibility to connect from PHP 5.5.0?

Comment: The driver source code might be available for download but I'm not aware of any third-party effort to contribute or even compile it. And I don't think the driver is a top priority for Microsoft. You'll probably have to downgrade and wait. You can [vote on the request](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790641/sql-server-driver-for-php-5-5) if you're inclined.

Comment: Thanks, I voted. Hopefully this issue will be addressed soon...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP 5.5 compiled with VC11, so the driver must be compiled with VC11 too. You can download PHP SQL Server driver (compiled with VC11) from here:

[SQL Server PHP Driver For PHP 5.5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86)

Comment: Those drivers work fine for me, thanks dude! Anyway, I think it would be useful to push up the votings for the "original" one: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790641/sql-server-driver-for-php-5-5#details

Answer (score 0):

Official driver from Microsoft has now been released (12/12/2014) .. you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

> Version 3.1 now supports PHP 5.5 and requires Microsoft ODBC Driver 11
>   (or higher) for SQL Server