# SQLSRV 3.0 install - undefined function sqlsrv_connect() IIS, php5.4.3,

Tags: php, windows, sqlsrv

I've read (and tried) every post I could find but no luck.
phpinfo does not show sqlsrv, but the ext folder is correct (tested) and dll's are there.

```
extension=php_pdo.dll //which I don't think is actually needed for this version
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
```

They are in c:/PHP/ext
Using FastCGI, did restart IIS and also the entire server.
This version of PHP (X86) and MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS has been installed & working for a year.

> Windows Server 2008 R2
>   PHPINFO
>   Compiler: MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
>   PHP Extension Build: API20100525,NTS,VC9

However, on PHPINFO, I see this on Configure Command:

```
"--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"
```

Just found and added:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_30_53_nts_vc9x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_30_53_nts_vc9x86.dll
```

Then:

```
extension_dir="C:\PHP\ext"
```

so I know I've installed the dll's correctly

Any help would be greatly appreciated - two days on this so far!

Comment: Reinstalled PHP, sqlsrv installed and working.  
However, doesn't actually update the database, even though it says it does.  This code produces "Updated", but database is not updated:

Comment: for ($i=0; $i <= $ectr; $i++) {
    $serverName = "XXXXX\SQLEXPRESS";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXX", "UID"=>"xxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxx" );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql = "select * from CampaignStats where var0='$campaign_id' and var1='$sent[$i]'";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

Comment: if( $stmt === false ) {
         $sql = "INSERT INTO CampaignStats (Var0,Var1,Var2,Var3,Var4,Var5,Var6,Var7) VALUES('$campaign_id','$sent[$i]','$open[$i]','$blocked[$i]','$bounced[$i]','$spam[$i]', '$click[$i]', '$status[$i]')";
    } 
    else  {
         $sql = "UPDATE CampaignStats set Var0='$campaign_id',Var1='$sent[$i]',Var2='$open[$i]', Var3='$blocked[$i]', Var4='$bounced[$i]', Var5='$spam[$i]', Var6='$click[$i]', Var7='$status[$i]' where var0='$campaign_id' and var1='$sent[$i]'";
    }

Comment: $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
         echo "Not updated<BR>";
       }
       else {
        echo "Updated<BR>";
       } 
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently upgraded my PHP and sqlsrv driver.  Here is what I did for the SQLSRV part:

First, my phpinfo() yields:

```
PHP Version 5.5.1
System: Windows NT HOSTNAME 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Business Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date: Jul 18 2013 10:37:55 
Compiler: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) 
Architecture: x86 


Configure Command
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"
```

Then I installed SQLSRV drivers to C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext the files, and added in php.ini:

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll 
[PHP_PDOSQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
```

and it works.  Altough I do not call functions directly (I use Yii framework), I also had the change the DSN:

> sqlsrv:Server=hostname_or_ip;Database=your_database_name;

Hope it helps.

## EDIT

I downloaded experimental/unofficial sqlsrv drivers for PHP 5.5 from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86 and updated my config to:

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll 
[PHP_PDOSQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

Found from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390741/2236500

Comment: Where did you find extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll ?  I cannot find that in any download I've tried.

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV30.EXE

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86

Comment: Those files are not in that download -
I need php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll & php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll

Comment: Found and tried 
    extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
    extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll

But still same error - still not showing in phpinfo() either.

Comment: Is there any other way to get a PHP to MS SQL connection going rather than sqlsrv, which obviously is extremely hard to get working (if it works at all based on the amount of posts I'm seeing)?

Comment: Have you tried to open a command line and run php -i?  There might be a reason appart PHP for not loading the DLLS -- like IIS using a different php.ini or something.

Comment: I changed some settings in the php.ini to test that I had the right one.  There's something else going on - maybe restarting IIS does not restart PHP or I don't have the right DLL's for Windows 2008 R2 - but I've tried nts, ts, VC6, VC9 - basically everything I could find. Maybe there are other DLL's needed - I read one post that a lot of other DLL's that seemed to have no connection had to be installed for this to work.  SQL Server Native Client 10.0 is installed already.  Can anyone tell me if any of this will help?  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978

Comment: OK - I did php -i and it says "program can't start because php5ts.dll is missing from your computer" - now I'm beginning to think php is not installed correctly.  Then it's the wrong version - but PHPINFO() says:
Compiler: MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
PHP Extension Build: API20100525,NTS,VC9

Comment: I've got 3 php folders because of install attempts and upgrades - how do I tell which one is running in IIS?

Comment: OK - here are the facts.
I put php5ts.dll in c:/php/ext because it wasn't there and when I clicked php.exe, that's what it asked for.  However, I'm not sure that's the php.exe that is installed because there are 3 folders of different php versions - I'm not even sure php is installed at all.  I only know that IIS uses php_cgi.exe.

I am updating the right php.ini - I set display_errors off and on and it's reflected on phpinfo().

Comment: I updated php.ini with:
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

I have placed the dll's in the correct folder (C:/php/ext) (none existed before this):
php_pdo.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
PHPINFO() makes no mention of sqlsrv at all.
I stll get the error "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()"

When I click on php.exe, I get "Unable to load php_pdo.dll - is not a valid Win32 application".

Comment: I will reinstall php5.3 - I see that there is a mismatch here.