# MSSQL slow with PHP Query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a PHP page that's slow whenever it goes to query a MSSQL database. I'm using the latest PHP and the standard SQL odbc drivers to the connect to the database. When accessing the page My sql profiler goes crazy.The query is displayed then

```
exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003,2,1,1
go
```

performs about 240 times before finally

```
exec sp_cursorclose 180150003
go
```

occurs and the page is displayed.

[image: Trace log Screenshot]

This is the query causing the headache:

```
    <?php
    $con = odbc_connect('Hesk','Trace_user','*******');
    $Assets = odbc_exec($con, "SELECT  AssetName,           AssetID From viewAssets ORDER BY [AssetName];");
?>
<table Border ="0"   width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:right" width="150"><?php echo $hesklang   ['asset']; ?>: <font class="important"></font>
</td>
<td width = "80%"><select name ="asset">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($Assets))
    {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['AssetID'] . '"' .            (($_SESSION['c_asset'] == $row['AssetID']) ? '              selected="selected"' : '')
    . '>' . $row['AssetName']. '</option>';
    }
    odbc_close($con);
?>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any idea how my code is causing this performance holdup?

Comment: Have you tried using the native mssql drivers for PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: database server side cursors are bad for performance...

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Hmm might give those drivers a try, are there normally isuues with the bundled odbc drivers?

Comment: @Tetsujin what are the alternatives? I've not really done anything different (I'm newish)

Comment: My experience is that ODBC drivers are not efficient in some circumstances.

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but the technique you're using is generating 242 calls from the PHP process to the database server. A better combination of drivers and choices in call construction should generate 1 call from the PHP process to the database server.

Comment: From my experience anything over 20-30 calls is very slow.

Comment: Shame there's no official drivers for PHP 5.5. I've found some drivers that should work with SQl server through this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289938/php-5-5-0-w-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-no-sqlsrv-connect.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the odbc_exec functions use cursors under the hood.  I'm not entirely sure who thought that was a good idea, but it's not.  Cursors are notoriously bad performers and generally a really bad idea unless you simply have no other way.

One option is to change your `odbc_connect` call to have the `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` flag.  A better option is to use the native drivers.

http://cct.me.ntut.edu.tw/ccteducation/chchting/aiahtm/computer/phphelp/function.odbc-connect.php.htm

Comment: Cheers so with two people telling me the drivers are an issue I think they'll be a job to upgrade them tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Try to measure time where is problem in connection or in query execution
If problem is in connection then change MSSQL name to IP

```
$con = odbc_connect('Hesk','Trace_user','*******');
```

For some reason my linux box was slow on resolving.

```
$con = odbc_connect('192.168.10.10','Trace_user','*******');
```